# why the value of map changed to a weird value?

Tags: dart

when adding some product to the cart

`addtoCart(_cartItem)` function

after executing this line
`_item['qty'] = _item['qty'] + _cartItem['qty'];`

both `_item['qty']` and `_cartItem['qty']` will be double of `_cartItem['qty']`

Can anyone help?

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> _cartItems =
      List.from(_shoppingCarts[_merchantId]['cartItems']);
  _cartItemsList = _cartItems.map((Map<String, dynamic> _item) { 
    if (_item['item_id'] == _cartItem['item_id'] &&
        _item['price'] == _cartItem['price']) {
      _isInCart = true; 
      _item['qty'] = _item['qty'] + _cartItem['qty'];

    }
    return _item;
  }).toList();
```